# Loading a GLFWImage with LodePNG

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, lodepng

Update: I wasn't assigning the `width` and `height` of the `GLFWimage` which caused it to not appear.

I'm trying to use lodePNG to load an image into GLFW to use as a texture, or icon.

I'm using a function very similar to what is shown [here](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/examples/example_decode.c).

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lodepng/lodepng.h>

unsigned char* decodeOneStep(const char* filename) {
    unsigned error;
    unsigned char* image;
    unsigned width, height;

    error = lodepng_decode32_file(&image, &width, &height, filename);
    if (error) printf("error %u: %s\n", error, lodepng_error_text(error));

    return image;
}
```

And later (after creating the window and its context), I'm calling this function to assign the `unsigned char*` taken by a `GLFWImage` to assign a Window Icon as follows:

```
GLFWimage icons[1];
unsigned char* imageData = decodeOneStep("assets/icons/icon.png");
icons[0].pixels = imageData;

// window is a GLFWwindow*, 1 is the image count
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, icons);
```

This compiles and runs fine, but the icon of my window hasn't changed (it's still the default one).

This is the image I'm trying to load (it's 48x48, which lodepng properly recognizes)

[image: icon]

I also `cout`-ed the `imageData` and got this, which looks like generic png data (although I'm not sure if this is helpful):

```
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                ╝±¥ µ) ?Û' AÑ Aö pñi                                 
                                                                                                                        
7╦< 5ð9 2È7 0Ï4 -▄1 *ß/ (Õ, Rù Oö$ Kæ2 GÄ? CïM                                                                         
                                                        LÀK J╗H G┐E E├C BÃ@ @╠> =ð; ;È8 8Ï6 6▄3 3Ó1 ^ÿ [ò, WÆ9 SÅF PîS 
Lè_ Içl Eäy                                                                                                 ‗÷‗ _ÑX ]®V 
Z¼S X░P V┤N S©L Q╝I N└G L─D J╚A G╠? Eð= CÈ: @Î8 mø? iÿ' fû3 bô@ _ÉL \ìX Xïd Uêq Qà} Néë Jû                             
                                                            ÐÏb hú[ eªX c¬V a«T ^▓Q \ÁO Z╣L X¢J U┴H S─E Q╚C N╠@ Lð> JË< 
w£" tÖ. pû: möF jæQ fÄ] cîi `ëu \åü Yäì Vüÿ R~ñ O|░ Ly╝                                                                 
            ·ü ¤ãf ╚Áe k¿Y i½V g»T d│R bÂO `║M ^¥K \┴H Y┼F W╚D U╠A Sð? Ç£) }Ö4 zù@ wöK sÆV pÅb mîm jèy gçä càÅ `éø ]Çª 
Z}▓ Vz¢ Sx╚ U║ï                                                                     ¹ç$ ÈÃl ╠Áj ãÑh p®Y n¡W l░T j┤R hÀP 
f╗N c¥L a┬I _┼G ]╔E îƒ$ ë£/ åÜ: âùE ÇòP }Æ[ zÉf vìq sï| pêç måÆ jâØ gü¿ bê¬ U┼1 U═* Vı$                                 
                                    ■ð¥ ­u1 ÐÂp ╩Ñn ├òl Âîh s«W q▒U oÁS m©Q k╗N i┐L g┬J eãH öƒ+ æ£5 ÄÜ@ ïÿK êòU àô` éÉj 
Äu |î yëè vçò R¼B R│< S╗6 S├/ S╦) TÈ"                                                                         ±{7 ÍÀu 
¤ªs ╚ûq ┴ço ╝yn x»W v▓U tÂS r╣Q p╝O n┐M ×í& £ƒ1 ÖØ; ûÜE ôÿO ÉûZ ìôd èæn çÅx OòR P£L PúG P¬A P▒; Q╣4 Q┴. Q╔'             
                                                                ±ü= µjB Ëªy ╠ûv ãçt └ys ║kq øÅd z│V xÂT v║R t¢P Ñí, óƒ6 
áØ@ ØøJ ÜÿT ùû^ MÇ` Må[ MîV MôQ NÜK NíE N¿? N»9 NÀ3 O┐, O╚%                                                             
                ‗çD þoI Ïª~ Ðû| ╩çz ─xx ¥kv ©^t │Sr ~┤V |ÀT {║R ¼í2 ®ƒ; ªØE Jln Kqj Kwe K}` KâZ KèU KæP KùJ LƒD Lª> L¡8 
LÁ1 L¢* Mã#                                                                             ¾ìK þuP ¦æu ıûü ╬ç ╚x} ┬k{ ╝^y 
ÀRw ▒Gu éÁV ┤ñ. èâa H^w Hdr Hin Ioi Iud I{_ IüY IêT IÄO IòI I£C Jñ= J½6 J│0 J╗) J─"                                     
                                        ¶öR Þ{V ¦c[ ┌ùç Ëçà ╠xé ãjÇ └^~ ║Q| ÁFz ░;x │éX FWz F\v Faq Fgm Gmh Grc Gx^ GX 
GàS GîM GôG GÜA Gí; G®5 H▒. H╣' H┬                                                                              §ÜY Úü] 
Ìia ▀ùì Ïçè Ðxê ╩jà ─]â ¥QÇ ╣E~ ┤;| ┤Ç\ ¼åV DYu D_q Ddl Ejg Epb Ev] E|W EâR EèL EæF Eÿ@ Eƒ: Eº3 E», EÀ% E└             
                                                                °¥Ø Ûçe Ìoh ËXl ▄çÉ ıxì ╬jè ╚]ê ┬Pà ╝Eâ À:ü Á}` ¡äZ ÑïT 
ØÆM Bbk Bgf Bma Bs\ CzV CÇQ CçK CÄE Cò? CØ8 CÑ1 C¡+ CÁ# ½┌ª                                                             
                    Ûìl ▀tp È]s ßçû ┌xô ËiÉ ╠\ì ãPï └Dê ╗9å Â{e «ü^ ªêX ØÅQ òûK @ee @k` @q[ @wU @~P @àJ @îD @ô= @ø7 @ó0 
@½) @│!                                                                                     Ùöt ▀zw Ècz ╩M} ▀wÖ Îiû ð\ô 
╩OÉ ─Cì ¥8ï Àxi »c ºå] ×ìV òöO î£H âúA >nZ >uT >{N >éH >ëB >æ< >ÿ5 >á. >¿' >▒                                          
                                            ýø| ÓÇ ıhé ╩Rä Òwƒ ▄iø ı[ÿ ╬Nò ╚BÆ ┬7É ©vn ░|g ¿âa ƒè[ ûÆT ìÖM âíE z®> <rS 
<yM <G ;çA ;Ä: ;û3 ;×, ;ª% ;«                                                                                     Ýóä 
Óçç ınë ╦Wî ┴BÄ ßhí ┘Z× ÊNø ╠Aÿ ã6ò ╣sr ▒zl ¿Çf áê_ ùÅX ìùQ äƒJ zºC p»; a▓7 9}F 9ä? 9ï9 9ô2 8ø+ 8ú# 8¼?                 
                                                                    ¯®î ßìÅ Ítæ ╦\ô ┴Fò µh¿ ÌZñ ÎMá ðAØ ╩5Ü ║pw ▓wq ®~k 
íàd ùî] ÄöV ä£O zñH p¡@ eÁ8 Z¥/ 6ü> 6ë7 6É0 6Ö) 5í! 5¬                                                                 
                    ´▒ò Ôöù ÍzÖ ╦bø ┴KØ ÃGú ÒY¬ █Lª È@ú ╬4ƒ ╗m| │tv ¬{p íéi ÿèb Åæ[ àÖT {óL p¬E e│= Z╝4 Nã, ;░. 3Ä. 3û' 
3× 2º                                                                                         Ôøá ÍÇó ╦hú ┴QÑ ©;ª ÞY░ 
ÓK¼ ┘?¿ Ê3Ñ ╝kü ┤q{ ½xt óÇn Öçg ÅÅ` àùY {ƒQ q¿J f▒B Z║9 N├1 B═( 5Ï 0ô% 0£ ßÝß                                         
                                                    Îç½ ╠m¼ ┴V¡ ©@« ÝXÂ ÕK▓ ¦>« Í2¬ ¢hå ÁnÇ ¼uz ú}s Üäl Éîe åö^ |£W qÑO 
f«G ZÀ> N┴6 B╦- 5ı# 'Ó +ª                                                                                             
        ╠s┤ ┴[Á ©EÂ »0À ÛJ© Ô=┤ █1░ ┐eï Âlà ¡s ñzx øür æëk çæc |Ü\ qóT f½L ZÁD N┐; A╔2 4Ë) 'Ì ð¸¤                     
                                                                                    ┬a¥ ©J¥ »5┐ ´I┐ þ<║ ▀0Â ├]û Àiï «pä 
Ñw~ øw æåp çÅi }ùa ráZ f®Q Z▓I N╝@ Aã7 4Ð.                                                                             
                                        ©OÃ «:Ã ª&Ã ý;┴ õ/╝ ╔Uá ©eÉ »mè ªtâ £|| Æâu êîn }ög rØ_ fªW Z░O N║F             
                                                                                                                    «?¤ 
Ñ*¤ ±:Ã Ú.┬ ÊE« ╣bû ░iÅ ºqë Øyé ôÇ{ êët ~æl rÜe gú]                                                                     
                                                                    ¸±¹ Ñ/Î Ø?Î ¯-╔ Ì5╝ ║_ø ▒fò ¿nÅ ×uê ö}ü ëåz ~Är ¾§¾ 
                                                                                                                        
                        Ï¥­ Ø▀ ¾+¤ Ù ╩ ╝\í ▓cø ®jö ƒrÄ özç èâÇ                                                         
                                                                                                    ¼iÙ ÑÕ ´Ð ¢Xº │`í 
¬gø áoö                                                                                                                 
                                                        ö´ ¶Î ¥U¡ Á\º                                                 
                                                                                                                        
            Õõ                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                ╩¦Â¡n[╔
```

Unfortunately I have no further idea how to fix this, so any help would be appreciated.

tl;dr: Why does `glfwSetWindowIcon` not change my window's icon to the with lodepng loaded image?

Comment: looks like `GLFWimage` has `height` and `width` fields as well, could leaving them empty be the problem?

Comment: Yes, I plugged 48 into both, and now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This compiles and runs fine, but the icon of my window hasn't changed (it's still the default one).

Probably because the data you're passing to `glfwSetWindowIcon` is in an invalid state.

You've *almost* got it right, but you're not specifying the width or height of the image being passed to `glfwSetWindowIcon`, and as a result, you're passing garbage data in. Best-case-scenario, the values are invalid for GLFW, and the data is being ignored. Worst-case-scenario, the values are incorrect but *technically valid*, and you get a buffer overflow and your program crashes.

Solve your problems by making sure your `decodeOneStep` function returns everything relevant:

```
GLFWImage decodeOneStep(const char* filename) {
    unsigned error;
    GLFWImage image;

    error = lodepng_decode_32_file(&(image.pixels), &(image.width), &(image.height), filename);
    if (error) printf("error %u: %s\n", error, lodepng_error_text(error));

    return image;
}

//............
GLFWimage icons[1];
icons[0] = decodeOneStep("assets/icons/icon.png");

// window is a GLFWwindow*, 1 is the image count
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, icons);
```

Since you're only passing one image, by the way, we can make this code a little simpler:

```
GLFWimage icon = decodeOneStep("assets/icons/icon.png");
glfwSetWindowIcon(window, 1, &icon);
```